# Show/hide div on select

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show div's depending on which value a select box is on. With my current script it is working, however, when I change the value of the select it shows the next div without hiding the previously selected one. I only want this JS script to show the currently selected div, not every div that is selected by the select box (ie. switching from one option to another).

**js and html**

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#contract_bid').hide();
            $('#equipment_purchase').hide();
            $('#hiring_employees').hide();
            $('#marketing').hide();
            $('#expansion').hide();
            $('#working_capital').hide();
            $('#inventory_purchase').hide();
            $('#refinancing').hide();
            $('#other').hide();
            $('#loan_application_requested_purpose').change(function(){
                if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Contract Bid') {
                    $('#contract_bid').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Equipment Purchase') {
                    $('#equipment_purchase').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Hiring Employees') {
                    $('#hiring_employees').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Marketing') {
                    $('#marketing').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Expansion/Renovation') {
                    $('#expansion').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Working Capital') {
                    $('#working_capital').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Inventory Purchase') {
                    $('#inventory_purchase').show(); 
                } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Refinancing') {
                    $('#refinancing').show(); 
                } else {
                    $('#other').show(); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

# HTML
<div id="contract_bid"></div>
<div id="equipment_purchase"></div>
<div id="hiring_employees"></div>
<div id="marketing"></div>
<div id="expansion"></div>
<div id="working_capital"></div>
<div id="inventory_purchase"></div>
<div id="refinancing"></div>
<div id="other"></div>
```

Comment: While showing curret div, you should hide all other divs each time

Comment: Give them all a class and do `$(".loan").hide()` before shoing the relevant one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

1. Give all the divs a class, for example "loan_purpose"
2. change your script to this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#loan_application_requested_purpose').on("change",function(){
    $(".loan_purpose").hide();
    // change all spaces to underscore and grab the first part of Expansion/
    var $div = $("#"+$(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"_").split("/")[0]);
    if ($div.length>0) $div.show();
    else $("#other").show(); 
  }).change(); // run change on load to show relevant already selected
});
```

Alternative to giving a class: if your divs have a common parent, you can do

```
$("#parentID > div").hide();
```

instead of

```
$(".loan_purpose").hide();
```

---

**Alternative solution:**

If you can change the values to reflect the IDs of the divs to show then the script will be much shorter:

```
<select id="loan_application_requested_purpose">
  <option value="other">Please select</option>
  <option value="equipment_purchase">Equipment Purchase</option>
  .
  .
  <option value="expansion">Expansion/Renovation</option>
</select>
```

Then my script needs only

```
$(function() {
    $('#loan_application_requested_purpose').on("change",function(){
      $(".loan_purpose").hide();
      $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
    }).change(); // run change on load to show relevant already selected
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added a class to all the of the divs called loan_purpose. Should I remove the div ID's (what I was using before)?

Comment: @Questifer You need id s while showing relevent div

Comment: Yes, keep the IDs and if you add the `value="id of div to show"` to the select options, the much shorter second version of my code can be used

Comment: Never mind. I have it working now. The only issue now is that with your update you required me to change the values of the select options. I am pushing the values to a third party api that somewhat require the names to be readable (eg Expansion Renovation instead of expansion_renovation).

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Will mark as correct answer after that.

Comment: See the first solution which now lowercases the values and grabs just the first part of `Expansion/renovation` to match the div with ID `"expansion"`

Comment: Thanks again for the clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add common class to all your divs:

```
<div id="other" class="section"></div>
<div id="contract_bid" class="section"></div>
<!-- and so on ... -->
```

Then it will allow you to reduce your code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.section').hide();

    $('#loan_application_requested_purpose').change(function () {

        $('.section').hide();

        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == 'Contract Bid') {
            $('#contract_bid').show();
        } else if (val == 'Equipment Purchase') {
            $('#equipment_purchase').show();
        }
        // other checks ....
        else {
            $('#other').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Note that it's cleaner to calculate value only once with `var val = $(this).val();` and use it later.

And finally even better would be to use CSS to initially hide sections (and get rid of the first `$('.section').hide();`):

```
.section {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="#myDivs">
<div id="contract_bid"></div>
<div id="equipment_purchase"></div>
<div id="hiring_employees"></div>
<div id="marketing"></div>
<div id="expansion"></div>
<div id="working_capital"></div>
<div id="inventory_purchase"></div>
<div id="refinancing"></div>
<div id="other"></div>
</div>

    if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Contract Bid') {
         $("#myDivs div").hide()                    
        $('#contract_bid').show(); 
    }else
    {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the visible div before you display the hidden div:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#contract_bid').hide();
        $('#equipment_purchase').hide();
        $('#hiring_employees').hide();
        $('#marketing').hide();
        $('#expansion').hide();
        $('#working_capital').hide();
        $('#inventory_purchase').hide();
        $('#refinancing').hide();
        $('#other').hide();
        $('#loan_application_requested_purpose').change(function(){
            // here comes the change:
            $('.loan_application_purpose:visible').hide();
            if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Contract Bid') {
                $('#contract_bid').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Equipment Purchase') {
                $('#equipment_purchase').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Hiring Employees') {
                $('#hiring_employees').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Marketing') {
                $('#marketing').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Expansion/Renovation') {
                $('#expansion').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Working Capital') {
                $('#working_capital').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Inventory Purchase') {
                $('#inventory_purchase').show(); 
            } else if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Refinancing') {
                $('#refinancing').show(); 
            } else {
                $('#other').show(); 
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contract_bid" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="equipment_purchase" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="hiring_employees" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="marketing" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="expansion" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="working_capital" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="inventory_purchase" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="refinancing" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
<div id="other" class="loan_application_purpose"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always hide all then show selected:

```js
$( '#trigger' ).change( function() {
  var selected_id = '#' + $('#trigger').val(); // Grab the ID to show
  $( '.foo' ).hide();                          // Hide all
  $( selected_id ).show();                     // Show selected
} ).change();                                  // Run at least once
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="trigger">
  <option>d1</option>
  <option>d2</option>
</select>

<div id="d1" class="foo">D1</div>
<div id="d2" class="foo">D2</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here, you have to hide other `div` in if or elseif condition like in if

```
if($('#loan_application_requested_purpose').val() == 'Contract Bid') {

 $('#contract_bid').show(); 
    $('#equipment_purchase').hide();
    $('#hiring_employees').hide();
    $('#marketing').hide();
    $('#expansion').hide();
    $('#working_capital').hide();
    $('#inventory_purchase').hide();
    $('#refinancing').hide();
}
```